# Is it "look further into the matter", "look into the matter further" or " further look into the matter"?

Tags: adverbs, word-order, syntax

> A. I will look further into the matter.
>
> B. I will further look into the matter.
>
> C. I will look into the matter further.

Which is grammatically correct? And Is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: I will look into the matter further.

Comment: Either A or C is idiomatic. B _could_ be interpreted as _Not only that, but I will look into the matter._ It's not idiomatic in English. Note that this is a very _formal_ way of expressing your thought; more informally, we might say "I'll see what else I can find out" or "I'll look into it."

Comment: B is wrong here. I will, furthermore, look into the matter.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - I agree with everything you said (except the part about the expression being very formal), and invite you to turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A is correct, C is correct but used less frequently. B is something that, as a native speaker, I find difficult to say without it feeling awkward and uncomfortable.

Comment: I think I've actually heard all three, but B sounds almost like corporate scripting vs natural English speech.

Comment: I don't agree that C is used less frequently. See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=look+further+into+the+matter%2Clook+into+the+matter+further%2Cfurther+look+into+the+matter&year_start=1908&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clook%20further%20into%20the%20matter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clook%20into%20the%20matter%20further%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfurther%20look%20into%20the%20matter%3B%2Cc0), which supports my sense that ***look into** [the matter]* has become a "standard sequence" that native speakers increasingly avoid breaking into with an adverb.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall hearing B used in conversation. It is valid to use A and C interchangeably. In conversation one may prefer A or C based on context.

A may imply one overlooked or missed a potentially important aspect of the subject.

B may imply awareness or priority of the subject has been raised.

Examples of context:

"I was unaware this problem was impacting you. I will look into the matter further."

"The problem is more complicated than we expected. I will look further into the matter."